# WMAudio Encoder DMO filter cuts the sound

Tags: audio, directshow, wma

I'm trying to use WMAudio Encoder DMO filter to record captured sound from the microphone, but it cuts about 1-2 seconds of recording in the end of sound. Does anybody faced this problem? Maybe there are any alternatives for WMA capturing for DirectShow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't capture, don't record with `WMAudio Encoder DMO`, do you? It is an encoder only. The symptom you are referring to - it sounds like there is a problem with flushing data in your filter graph, when you stop encoding something is not processing the pending remainder of data, and it is not necessarily `WMAudio Encoder DMO`.

Perhaps you could quick swap the encoder with another one to see if you have more luck with this alternate option, and this would suggest the faulty component in first place.

Comment: I haven't such problems with other encoders such Vorbis Encoder. I've faced this problem only when I tried to use WMAudio Encoder DMO.

Comment: My graph is CaptureDevice -> WMAudio Encoder DMO -> WAV Dest -> FileWriter

Comment: Windows Media codecs (which exactly you are using?) have certain block length and you are possibly seeing a cut-off on an incomplete block. I think that if you inject some silence when you stop capturing, this would work the problem around.

Comment: I have just added 1200 ms delay before mediacontrol.Stop() method and it works good